# 'foundation watch' in Foundation 6 not serving project files

Tags: npm, gulp, zurb-foundation

I've installed [Zurb Foundation 6](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html) after having used past versions of Foundation thru the years.

```
npm install -g foundation-cli
```

I then ran the commands as outlined in Getting Started:

```
foundation new
// A website (Foundation for Sites)
// project-name
// Basic Template: includes a Sass compiler
```

The project directory was created, then:

```
cd project-name
foundation watch
```

And the result is:

```
$ foundation watch

> foundation-sites-template@1.0.0 start /project-name
> gulp

[19:28:34] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/test-foundation-6/gulpfile.js
[19:28:34] Starting 'sass'...
[19:28:35] Finished 'sass' after 1.26 s
[19:28:35] Starting 'default'...
[19:28:35] Finished 'default' after 11 ms
```

At which point nothing else happens - there are no errors. I've opened `localhost:8080`, as well as a few other ports but no pages are loading. If I open the `index.html` file directly in the browser it renders fine.

I also tried `foundation build` but no `/build` directory is created.

I read in some places there could be issues if the past (gem) version of Foundation was installed, so I went through the steps to uninstall the gem (`gem uninstall foundation`) then install via `npm` again. But same result as before.

Any ideas on why `foundation watch` isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `npm start`,please ? Maybe works.

Comment: Same thing as before. Appears to start fine, no errors, but no server at `localhost:8080`